# Unreachable statement error when trying to return from a while loop - Java

Tags: java, while-loop, return, break

```
static long minDaysToEmpty(long C, long l) {
    long previousFill=C;
    long day=1;
    long currentFill=C;
    while(true){
        currentFill=Math.min(C,(previousFill-(day))+l);
        previousFill=currentFill;
        day++;
        if(day>3){
            return day;
        }
    }
    return day;
}
```

This code throws a compile time error.

```
Test.java:15: error: unreachable statement return day;
```

I don't understand why this statement can't be reached.

On doing the below modification to the original code, the if block is reachable

```
if(day>3){
  break;
}
```

But inside the same block return statement is unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

Since the while loop is `while (true)` and contains no `break` statements, the only way the loop can exit is by fulfilling this condition, which is already returning from the method

```
if (day > 3) {
    return day;
}
```

Therefore the `return day` at the bottom of the method is not possible to reach.

Just remove that line `return day;` at the bottom of the method. Provided your logic is correct and `day` will eventually be greater than 3, you don't need it.

Alternatively, choose a proper condition rather than `while (true)`, or add a break statement.

Comment: Yea got my mistake. The error is because of the lower return statement and not because of the return statement inside the while loop.

Comment: @user16320675 My bias for hating while loop and lack of sleep made me skip that part. :)